# Django Form Logic: Split and display prefilled values

Tags: django, django-forms

Let's say I have a model that holds several different charfields.

models.py

```
class Items(models.Model):
    languages = models.Charfield(...)
    title = models.Charfield(...)
    audio = models.Charfield(...)
```

The data is saved within each with a delimiter ("||").  I would like to create a form that splits the data then prefills the value with the saved data.

Theoretically:

```
{'languages': 'English||French||German'}
{'title': '1.1||Red Balloon||Banana'}
{'audio': 'yes||no||yes'}
```

Would be split to:

```
{'languages': ['English', 'French', 'German']}
{'title': ['1.1', 'Red Balloon', 'Banana']}
{'audio': ['yes', 'no', 'yes']}
```

Then each value would auto-populate the value field. Eventually displaying as:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="languages[]" value="English"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="title[]" value="1.1"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="audio[]" value="yes"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="languages[]" value="French"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="title[]" value="Red Balloon"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="audio[]" value="no"></td>
</tr>
...
```

As each row would have a different amount of 'languages', for example, what is the preferred way to create this type of form.  I am using Django 1.11. First question posted, so if I have missed something within this post, would you kindly let me know?  I also have searched for information related to this, however I have yet to find a solution. Thanks!

--Edited to reflect that charFields hold the user input.  In this example, the inputs 'languages' and 'title' are not consistent enough to use them as multiple-choice fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#module-django.forms.formsets).

In your case you'd want to first define some sort of `ItemForm`:

```
from django import forms
class ItemForm(forms.Form):
    language = forms.CharField()
    setting = forms.CharField()
    audio = forms.CharField()
```

In your views.py, you can then define a formset with the initial form data:

```
from django.forms import formset_factory
from myapp.forms import ItemForm

item = Items.objects.all()[0] # replace this with your actual query
languages = item.languages.split('||')
settings = item.settings.split('||')
audios = item.audio.split('||')
ItemFormSet = formset_factory(ItemForm, extra=len(languages))
formset = ItemFormSet(initial=[
    {'language': language,
     'setting': setting,
     'audio':audio,
    } for language, setting, audio in zip(languages, settings, audios)])
```

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should simply consider [`ChoiceFields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield).